# JS: How to change the style of multiple Elements with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors

I've created the following lines of code to animate the gradient of the blue buttons (https://konzerthofner.webflow.io/events/2-11-im-11-der-auftakt-2020). Everything works as expected, until I decide to use more than one button of this kind. In this case only the first button gets animated. I think the problem is, that I'm always selecting the first element inside the DOM with the corresponding class. Unfortunately I'm not able to provide a working solution for this.

My JS to change one button:

```
var cta = document.querySelector('.khctaglobal');
cta.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  console.log("mousemove success");
    let rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  let x = e.clientX - rect.left;
  cta.style.setProperty('--x', x + "px");
});
```

My failed attempt to solve this problem:

```
var cta = document.querySelector('.khctaglobal');
cta.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  console.log("mousemove success");
    let rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  let x = e.clientX - rect.left;
  cta.forEach(el => el.style.setProperty('--x', x + "px"));
});
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: `querySelector` only returns one element.  `querySelectorAll` returns potentially multiple

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link. This definitely helps to understand the principle behind this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `querySelectorAll` to grab the entire list of elements by that selector (class).

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.khctaglobal').forEach(cta => ...);
```

You can conveniently call [`NodeList.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) to loop over the selected elements.

### Example

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.khctaglobal').forEach(cta => {
  cta.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
    console.log("mousemove success");
    let rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    let x = e.clientX - rect.left;
    cta.style.setProperty('--x', x + "px");
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot of mate! Solved!